# How to reload chrome package app programatically?

Tags: google-chrome, package

I want to reload my chrome package app programatically...
location.reload(true); or window.location.reload(); does not work for me.
As I have a sandbox frame in my app so on using above mentioned lines blank screen appears.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what are you trying to do.
Packaged app is called packaged since its all packed in one file and loaded with it, there is nothing to reload there.

If you need to reload something loaded from outside, like iframe or webview, you can reload them separatly, like

youriframe.reload()

or

yourwebview.reload()